# SSO without cookie

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I want to use SSO on my php website,i implemented this by cookie an redirection method,but redirection is not so good for google redirection ,
I want to now implement without cookie or by some ajax,

any help ??

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are the only way to implement session handling with any sort of reliability over HTTP. But you should never set up cross-domain cookies - they won't work in most cases anyway. The process of setting up SSO for web applications has been described many, many times, both here and elsewhere on the internet. Try Google if you don't unserstand the answers already referenced here.

Comment: i know this post is answered many times but i want SSO without cookie or any other method.

Comment: Telepathy is not yet a viable medium for computer-to-computer interaction.  You need to somehow pass some info between apps.